# Several triggers not fully working and code is extra long

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, toggle, show

I have a page that has 7 image boxes, these boxes are alert boxes for our customers agents for any type of alerts being sent out. I have them all set as a link, when clicked the box turns from orange to blue and an information box is opened next to it, each image has its own info box. I have it partially working but it is not function how I want. I need it so if box1 is opened and the user clicks box2 the box1 should revert back to orange and its info box needs to close so that box2's info box can populate the space. Right now the image boxes stay blue when you click on other boxes and the code I have to close the info boxes is bugging out if you click off another image box. Here is part of my code and my HTML:
(Update) Here is a jsbin link of my example as it should be working. However, the click event is not working on my system, its not even trying to scroll to the top of teh page which normally happens when the trigger breaks but the href=# is there. Here is my new code:) [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ecelil/2/edit)

```
  //JS
  $(document).ready(function () {

        function assignClickHandlerFor(boxNum) {

            $('#a' + boxNum).click(function (evt) {

                // returning false at the end implictly does these two lines. 
                evt.preventDefault();
                evt.stopPropagation();

                var $aBox = $(evt.currentTarget); // points to the  element 
              (ie, the link) clicked. 

                // locate the div that has both the `.active` class and the `.alertBox2` class
                var $prevAlert = $('.alertBox2.active');
                $prevAlert.find('.blue').hide();
                $prevAlert.find('.orange').show();
                $prevAlert.removeClass('active');

                $('.alertDetails').hide();


                $abox.find('.blue').show();
                $abox.find('.orange').hide();
                $abox.addClass('active');

                // show the required alert.
                $('#d' + boxNum).show();
            });

        }

        var i;

        for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
            assignClickHandlerFor('Box' + i);
        }

    });
  //CSS
      .alertBox2
  {
      float:left; display:block; 
   }
   .alertDetails
   {
     display:none; background-color:#fff; width:250px; height:585px; float:left;                             position:relative; left:5px; top:8px; 
      }

    //HTML 
               <div><a href="#" id="aBox1" class="alertBox2" >
                    <span class="infoBox orange">
                        <img src="Images/orange_alert_box.jpg" alt="Orange Info Box" />
                    </span>
                    <span class="infoBox blue" style="display: none;">
                        <img src="Images/blue_alert_box.jpg" alt="Blue Info Box" />
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div> 
            <div><a href="#" id="aBox2" class="alertBox2">
                    <span class="infoBox orange">
                        <img src="Images/orange_alert_box.jpg" alt="Orange Info Box" />
                    </span>
                    <span class="infoBox blue" style="display: none;">
                        <img src="Images/blue_alert_box.jpg" alt="Blue Info Box" />
                    </span>
                </a></div>                
            <div><a href="#" id="aBox3" class="alertBox2">
                    <span class="infoBox orange">
                        <img src="Images/orange_alert_box.jpg" alt="Orange Info Box" />
                    </span>
                    <span class="infoBox blue" style="display: none;">
                        <img src="Images/blue_alert_box.jpg" alt="Blue Info Box" />
                    </span>
                </a></div>                     
        </div>
        <p id="alertDP">Click on any Alert to the left to see details</p>

        <div class="alertDetails" id="dBox1">
                Box1
        </div>
         <div class="alertDetails" id="dBox2">
                Box2
        </div>
         <div class="alertDetails" id="dBox3">
                Box3
        </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! For starters, if you could create a JS Fiddle on (http://jsfiddle.net) with the bare minimum html/js/css to reproduce your issue, the chances of getting a quicker and effective response will increase. Right now, we have to mentally visualize what the code will do and how certain changes may affect the operation.

Comment: I am sorry, but I couldn't gather if you have more than one issue? The first issue is only one info box should be shown at a time. Is there another issue as well? Does the answer I just posted solve the first?

Comment: With it having images running it its hard to use js fiddle. I will try to write some code that works nearly the same, about to leave the office for the day now tho.

Comment: If boxA is selected already and it has been turned blue and the user selects boxB or boxC I need boxA to turn back to its original state of the orange image. I also need boxA's info box to go back to being hidden.

Comment: You don't need to use images. You could just write text there, Blue/Orange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** A link demonstrating my understanding of your issue. http://jsbin.com/ecelil/1/edit

A few observations, clicking on any one `aBox` only toggles its own `infoBox`. In the click handler for `aBox2` you seem to have noticed that and tried to fix it by passing three infobox selectors to jQuery. However jQuery doesn't work that way. It accepts only one selector. That selector can however match those three elements.

Replace the first line of each of the three `aBox` click handlers with `$('.infoBox1, .infoBox2, .infoBox3').toggle();`

As for the code being too long, well, `for` loops, `variables` and `css class selectors` are your friends :)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function assignClickHandlerFor(boxNum) {

        $('#a' + boxNum).click(function (evt) {

            // returning false at the end implictly does these two lines. 
            evt.preventDefault();
            evt.stopPropagation(); 

            var $aBox = $(evt.currentTarget); // points to the  element (ie, the link) clicked. 

            // locate the div that has both the `.active` class and the `.alertBox2` class
            var $prevAlert = $('.alertBox2.active'); 
            $prevAlert.find('.blue').hide();
            $prevAlert.find('.orange').show();
            $prevAlert.removeClass('active');

            $('.alertDetails').hide();


            $aBox.find('.blue').show();
            $aBox.find('.orange').hide();
            $aBox.addClass('active');

            // show the required alert.
            $('#d' + boxNum).show();
        });

    };

    var i;

    for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        assignClickHandlerFor('Box'+i);
    }

});

// css

.blue-info-box {
    background-image: url('Images/blue_alert_box.jpg');
}

.orange-info-box {
    background-image: url('Images/orange_alert_box.jpg');
}

// html

<div>
    <a href="#" id="aBox1" class="alertBox2" >
        <span class="infoBox orange">
            <img src="Images/orange_alert_box.jpg" alt="Orange Info Box" />
        </span>
        <span class="infoBox blue" style="display: none;">
            <img src="Images/blue_alert_box.jpg" alt="Blue Info Box" />
        </span>
    </a>
</div> 
<div>
    <a href="#" id="aBox2" class="alertBox2">
        <span class="infoBox orange">
            <img src="Images/orange_alert_box.jpg" alt="Orange Info Box" />
        </span>
        <span class="infoBox blue" style="display: none;">
            <img src="Images/blue_alert_box.jpg" alt="Blue Info Box" />
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#" id="aBox3" class="alertBox2">
        <span class="infoBox orange">
            <img src="Images/orange_alert_box.jpg" alt="Orange Info Box" />
        </span>
        <span class="infoBox blue" style="display: none;">
            <img src="Images/blue_alert_box.jpg" alt="Blue Info Box" />
        </span>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="alertDetails" id="dBox1">
        Box1
</div>
 <div class="alertDetails" id="dBox2">
        Box2
</div>
 <div class="alertDetails" id="dBox3">
        Box3
</div>
```

Comment: Ya I tossed that line with teh 3 as a test, my skills with JQ are still somewhat basic so I try a few aves before asking. Figured I would leave it in to show what I have done. I will try this and see if it helps. Thnx

Comment: One issue with this, which is why I had images inside the span tag, an empty span tag won't show up on the screen. I am going to keep playing with what you wrote and see if I can't get it to work with an image inside the span.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/new-css-image-replacement-technique/ .Place some dummy text in the spans.

Comment: It only fills the area that has text, Even tried a few &nbsp; and didn't work the way I need it. Plus I can't have text in the boxes, once this trigger mech is finished I will be overlaying each box with a sized <div> that will hold my calls for the code behind variables that will be running the output messages in the box. This isn't just a project for fun or learning, this is for my company's website's alert center, so everything will have a use in the end.

Comment: I mentioned dummy text, because the image replacement techniques will hide the text. The text was purely for not having an empty span. `span` by default is an inline display element. You will have to give it a width and height, make it display:block. That change might require other related css changes that I can't predict as I am currently flying blind without a jsfiddle. ... Let me see if I can rewrite the js code to work with images instead of background images :)

Comment: Thnx for the link to that maybe helpful.

Comment: Updated my answer. I have retained your html structure. Modified the css class names a bit.

Comment: Well that solves the boxes being there but the click event doesn't work on this.

Comment: I have added a link to a working solution. http://jsbin.com/ecelil/1/edit . If that doesn't match your example, please edit it to your situation. And share that link in your question.

Comment: Ya that is pretty much working teh exact way I need it to, but I can't seem to get it to function on my system.

Comment: Ok. That's something. Please update your question to include the code you are using. The one that integrates my solution. Also update the question with what is not working. The comments are getting too long and the **what is not working** is important for all readers to know.

Comment: I got it working, the jsbin code you had was a little diff then this code and when I copied it over it worked. Thanks a lot for your assistance, and a great tutor session.

Comment: Glad to help. Though, an upvote on the answer as well would be nice :)

Comment: I would be more than happy to upvote it but sadly I don't have enough rep on the site yet. I am 9 rep points shy.